# Dropzone.js upload box will not display

Tags: javascript, html, css, dropzone.js

I am trying to incorporate Dropzone's upload feature into my Laravel 4 app.

I have include the js/css file in my master layout like so

```
{{ HTML::style('packages/bootstrap/css/dropzone.css') }}
{{ HTML::script('packages/bootstrap/js/dropzone.js') }}
```

Then I included the html form where I want the box to appear, in add.blade.php

```
<form action="/file-upload" class="dropzone" id="my-awesome-dropzone"></form>
```

But when I navigate to listings/add I cannot see the dropzone.
Is there anything else I need to include for it to show up?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are not nesting form tags, that would prevent the box showing.

Comment: this was the issue with mine...kudos

Answer (score 0):

Instantiate the dropzone class on the page.

`$("#my-awesome-dropzone").dropzone({ url: "/file-upload" });`

This way you could also add in some options that [dropzone](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) ships with.

Comment: That did not do much. I still can't see anything in the <div> where I pasted the form code.

Comment: Yes I did. `$(function() { $("#my-awesome-dropzone").dropzone({ url: "/file-upload" }); });`

Comment: And you included Jquery before this? Any errors show in firebug or other dev tools?

Comment: Yes, I have included jQuery files and no errors related to this in firebug.

Comment: "no errors related to this in firebug"  leads me to believe there are some errors. If there is an error in your JavaScript, anything after it will not be executed.

Comment: I got rid of all the errors but I just noticed one related to dropzone, it's the only one left. `ncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'dropzone' add:439
(anonymous function) add:439
fire jquery-1.9.1.js:1037
self.fireWith jquery-1.9.1.js:1148
jQuery.extend.ready jquery-1.9.1.js:433
completed`

Comment: For some reason it doesn't seem to have access to your dropzone.js file. Make sure the instantiation is after both Jquery and the dropzonejs files. 
Also, although it shouldn't matter, if you have the instantiation code in an external js file.. try putting in in the page file to see if that helps.